# CSS question -- removing a space at top of site

Tags: css, margin

How do I remove the gray area here: https://img.skitch.com/20110808-ncu19ep6fw47s9pxhqxa99qmcb.jpg

In style.css, padding is:

padding: 0;

...I've tried changing this:

```
#page { margin-top: 0; }
```

to the following things:

```
#page { margin-top: 5px !important; }

#page { margin-top: -5px !important; }

#page { margin-top: 0px !important; }

#page { margin-top: 0 !important; }
```

...but these things showed no noticeable change.

Here's the site in case it helps: http://richardclunan.com/

Thanks,

Comment: I've now removed the 2em; but there seems to be a very small line of gray at the top of the site -- like maybe 1px gray line across the top of the site -- how do I get rid of this? see here: http://richardclunan.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this css style:

```
 #page {
    margin: 2em auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
}
```

to

```
 #page {
    margin: 0px auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
}
```

also change

```
#branding {
    border-top: 2px solid #BBBBBB;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

to this:

```
#branding {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess all the other answers would do the trick too. I followed this one because I'm a beginner and the format of "change [this] to [this]" made me totally sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Give the below style:

```
 body {
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        }


    #page {
    margin:0 auto;
    max-width:1000px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add the same rules to the `<body>` and/or `<html>` elements:

```
body, html { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have this:

```
#page {
    margin: 2em auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
}
```

in your `style.css`. That gives `#page` a top and bottom margin of 2em. You probably want this:

```
#page {
    margin: 0 auto 2em auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
}
```

That's the same as `margin: 2em auto` but with a zero top margin.